# Delete Object out of ArrayList<?> with another instance of the same object

Tags: java, arraylist, gson

So I have an undefined object, which I want to delete out of an Array list with another undefined object with the same values so I can have one class which can handle every Object I throw at it and don't have to create a different method for every Object type.

The problem is, that even though the content of the Objects is the same, because it is another instance the overall value is different.

like:
Msg.TradeMsg@1d97b82
Msg.TradeMsg@1a3337fb\

Even though these 2 Objects have the same values they are different and won't return true with a .equals

So my question is, how can I remove an object from the array list, when it has the same fields but I don't know what the Object class is?

Or is there a easier way?

Code:

```java
//valueToDelete can be of any type like User, Items, Trade...
public void deleteFromJson(Object valueToDelete, String fileLocation) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Object> oldValues = new ArrayList<>();

        //If valueTiDelete is null, the whole content of the file will be deleted
        if (valueToDelete != null) {
            //Get Content out of array and add it to the ArrayList
            for (Object oldValue : updateOldValues(fileLocation)) {
                oldValues.add(gson.fromJson(oldValue.toString(), valueToDelete.getClass()));
            }

            //This does not work, because the objects are 2 different instances but still have all the same fields.
            //How can I remove an object from the array list, when it has the same fields but I don't know what the Object class is?
            oldValues.remove(valueToDelete);
        }

        // Write updated content in file
        Writer writer = new FileWriter(fileLocation);
        gson.toJson(oldValues, writer);

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head right in your question: they won't return true with a `.equals()`.  You need to override the `.equals()` method such that it detects equivalent objects to your liking.  Most IDEs will then also generate your `hashCode()` method for you once you write the `equals()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To verify if two objects, of unknown and varying classes, are equal in the value which they contain, you can either

1. override both `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode` in all classes that might ever go into that list, or
2. use [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html) to probe inside the object and deep check for equality

The second is quite hard to do, and prone to errors, if not done carefully.
[Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/), for instance, does this to accomplish its *dirty checking* functionality, so I wouldn't say it is a bad practice, but definitely lingers in the gray area.

<sub>Side note: having such a need usually indicates the need for a re-designing of the model</sub>